# Директория .next не создается при сборке контейнера

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nextjs, next.js

Пытаемся запустить проект через docker compose, со стороны бекенда всё хорошо, а с фронтом на next js проблемы.

Запускал compose на своем компе, запускал на виртуальной машине, и всё работает, но на предоставленной нам виртуальной машине для проекта всё собирается, но не может запуститься из-за отсутствия папки .next
Ниже я приведу разные примеры, но суть у них одна - чего-то не хватает из .next или же самой .next нету.

Вообще, выглядит как бред полный, но я уже не знаю что делать.

Файл next.config.js:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
    output: "standalone",
  };
```

Файл package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookies-next": "^4.1.1",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "sharp": "^0.33.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Файл docker-compose:

```
front:
        container_name: next-app
        build:
            context: ./front
            dockerfile: Dockerfile

        environment:
            - HOST="нужный хост"
            - NODE_ENV=development
            - NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

        env_file:
            - ./front/.env

        depends_on:
            - back

        restart: always

        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
```

Нынешний* файл Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest 
LABEL author="Ivan Orlovsky"

WORKDIR /front

COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
RUN npm ci

RUN npm run build

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Перепробовано миллион докерфайлов, результат один - у меня всё окей у себя и на виртуалке, на той виртуалке - всевозможные ошибки по типу "чо-то не найдено. Были перепробованы докерфайлы из официального репозитория vercel, разных гайдов на ютубе, прочих обсуждалок, но в итоге я пришел к самому простому варианту, который собирается, но не запускается с ошибкой:

[image: Ошибка при запуске(с dockerfile выше)]

Еще были такие ошибки:

При использовании CMD ["node", "server.js"](опять же, у меня всё хорошо, а на той виртуалке это): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При использовании рефернса с официального репозитория(с копированием из .next папки):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка на втором фото связана с кривым копированием, однако, там точно также будет при правильном копировании, что он не видит где этот server.js создается в папке .next(ну, видимо, как и всю эту папку)